# Spring: What parser to use to parse security expressions

Tags: spring-security, spring-el

I would like to parse standard security expressions like `hasRole` etc. to get their value in a variable (in a JSP). How can I do that? `SpelExpressionParser` is the standard EL parser, but I don't think it will parse the security expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest approach is to use a `<sec:authorize>` tag and modify a desired variable inside its body.

If you actually want to evaluate expressions manually, look at the source of `AuthorizeTag` - it gets the first bean of type [`WebSecurtyExpressionHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/expression/WebSecurityExpressionHandler.html) from the web application context and uses it to obtain `ExpressionParser` and `EvaluationContext`.

Answer (score 0):

I've posted an answer in this topic here - [How to parse spring security expressions programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467823/how-to-parse-spring-security-expressions-programmatically-e-g-in-some-controll). I think this answers your question also.